# Customise train_step in model.fit() Tensorflow Keras - InvalidArgumentError: Operation 'while' has no attr named '_XlaCompile'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a custom multi-input and -output model which uses a learning algorithm as proposed in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07593.pdf) paper. The model itself works fine without the custom learning algorithm which I use as a baseline. The problem I encounter is that the code got stuck in the train_step function in the DebiasModel class at code line:

```
mc_pred = self.main_classifier([xu, xs], training=True)
```

It did not return an error. After running for an hour, I interrupted the kernel and it returns the error message saying:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Operation 'while' has no attr named '_XlaCompile'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError: Operation 'gradients/while_grad/Placeholder_28' has no attr named '_read_only_resource_inputs'.
```

I am not sure what the issue is and I have tried to use persistent=True in tf.GradientTape as well instead of declaring two gradientTapes in single watch. But, exactly the same error occurs.

Does anyone have any idea what this issue is? And how it can be solved?

I am using Tensorflow V2.3.0 and Keras V2.4.0

**Source Code**

```
class model_components:

  def mitigation_expert():
    inputs = Input(shape=(300,), dtype=tf.int32, name="me_input")
    x = Embedding(num_tokens, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_length, trainable=False, name="me_embedding")(inputs)
    x = LSTM(300, return_sequences=False, name="me_lstm")(x)

    model = Model(inputs, x)

    return model

  def control_expert():
    inputs = Input(shape=(22,), dtype=tf.int32, name="ce_input")
    y = Dense(19, activation='relu', name="ce_hidden")(inputs)

    model = Model(inputs, y)

    return model

  def main_classifier():
    # Expert components
    me = model_components.mitigation_expert()
    ce = model_components.control_expert()

    # Main classifier
    ensemble = concatenate([me.output, ce.output], name="pred_ensemble")
    pred_output = Dense(319, activation="relu", name="pred_hidden")(ensemble)
    pred_output = Dense(3, activation="softmax", name="pred_output")(pred_output)

    model = Model(inputs=[me.input, ce.input], outputs=pred_output, name="main_classifier")

    return model
  
  def adversary_classifier():
    # Mitigation Expert component
    me = model_components.mitigation_expert()

    # Adversary classifier
    adv_output = Dense(300, activation='relu', name="adv_hidden")(me.output)
    adv_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="adv_output")(adv_output)

    model = Model(inputs=me.input, outputs=adv_output, name="adversary_classifier")

    return model
```

```
def tf_normalize(x):
  return x / (tf.norm(x) + np.finfo(np.float32).tiny)

class DebiasModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, main_classifier, adversary_classifier):
        super(DebiasModel, self).__init__()
        self.main_classifier = main_classifier
        self.adversary_classifier = adversary_classifier

    def compile(self, mc_optimizer, adv_optimizer, mc_loss, adv_loss, debias_param):
        super(DebiasModel, self).compile()
        self.mc_optimizer = mc_optimizer
        self.adv_optimizer = adv_optimizer
        self.mc_loss = mc_loss
        self.adv_loss = adv_loss
        self.debias_param = debias_param

    def train_step(self, data):
      # Unpack data from model.fit()
      x, y, sample_weight = data

      # Unpack input and output features
      xu, xs = x
      y_mc = y['pred_output']
      z_adv = y['adv_output']

      # Unpack sample_weights
      mainClass_weights = sample_weight["pred_output"]
      protectClass_weights = sample_weight["adv_output"]

      # Generate prediction and compute loss for Main_Classifier
      with tf.GradientTape() as mc_tape, tf.GradientTape() as me_mc_tape:
        mc_pred = self.main_classifier([xu, xs], training=True)
        mc_loss = self.mc_loss(y_mc, mc_pred, sample_weight=mainClass_weights)
      
      # Compute and Apply Gradients for CE & Main Classifier
      mc_trainable_vars = self.main_classifier.trainable_weights[3:]
      mc_grads = mc_tape.gradient(mc_loss, mc_trainable_vars)
      self.mc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(mc_grads, mc_trainable_vars))

      # Generate prediction and compute loss for Adversary_Classifier
      with tf.GradientTape() as adv_tape, tf.GradientTape() as me_adv_tape:
        adv_pred = self.adversary_classifier(xu)
        adv_loss = self.adv_loss(z_adv, adv_pred, sample_weight=protectClass_weights)
      
      # Compute and Apply Gradients for CE & Main Classifier
      adv_trainable_vars = self.adversary_classifier.trainable_weights[3:]
      adv_grads = adv_tape.gradient(adv_loss, adv_trainable_vars)
      self.adv_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(adv_grads, adv_trainable_vars))

      # Compute and Apply Gradients to debias ME
      me_adv_debias_trainable_vars = self.adversary_classifier.trainable_weights[:3]
      adv_debias_grads = me_adv_tape.gradient(adv_loss, me_adv_debias_trainable_vars)
      adv_debias_dict = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
          tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(me_adv_debias_trainable_vars, adv_debias_grads), 0)
      
      me_mc_debias_trainable_vars = self.main_classifier.trainable_weights[:3]
      mc_debias_grads = me_mc_tape.gradient(mc_loss, me_mc_debias_trainable_vars)

      me_grads = []

      for g, v in zip(mc_debias_grads, me_mc_debias_trainable_vars):
        unit_adv = tf_normalize(adv_debias_dict.lookup(v))
        g -= tf.math.reduce_sum(g * unit_adv) * unit_adv
        g -= self.debias_param * adv_debias_dict.lookup(v)
        me_grads.append(zip(g, v))
      
      self.mc_optimizer.apply_gradients(me_grads)
      
      return {"pred_loss": mc_loss, "adv_loss": adv_loss}
```

```
model = DebiasModel(model_components.main_classifier(),
                    model_components.adversary_classifier())

model.compile(mc_optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              adv_optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              mc_loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              adv_loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              debias_param=1)

epoch = 5
sample_weights = {
    "pred_output": mainClass_weight,
    "adv_output": protectClass_weight,}

model.fit(x=[xu_train, xs_train],
          y={"pred_output": y_train, "adv_output": z_train},
          validation_data=([xu_val, xs_val], {"pred_output": y_val, "adv_output": z_val}),
          sample_weight=sample_weights, epochs=epoch, batch_size=256, verbose=1)
```

**Error Traceback**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in get_attr(self, name)
   2485       with c_api_util.tf_buffer() as buf:
-> 2486         pywrap_tf_session.TF_OperationGetAttrValueProto(self._c_op, name, buf)
   2487         data = pywrap_tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(buf)

InvalidArgumentError: Operation 'while' has no attr named '_XlaCompile'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
51 frames
ValueError: Operation 'while' has no attr named '_XlaCompile'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
InvalidArgumentError: Operation 'gradients/while_grad/Placeholder_28' has no attr named '_read_only_resource_inputs'.
```

Note: I have not added the full traceback, but if needed I can provide it. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I am still working on this issue and have opened a bug report as well. You can follow this here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42306 - it is quite strange because the same error occurs constantly. Even when trying with other models.

Comment: It seems that the forward pass in the Keras Functional API Model triggers the error which is quite odd and I don't understand why..